# Random numbers in assembly

Tags: assembly, random

How can I randomize a number using Assembly tasm? I have to rendomize numbers for coordinates... I study assembly on basic level but I know that there is a way using clock. I have to randomize 6 numbers in second so it doesn't work....
sorry about my english!

Comment: Use a [Pseudorandom number generator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator)?

Comment: If you just want something simple you could use implement a [linear feedback shift register](https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/app-notes/index.mvp/id/4400).

Comment: Any highly random solution is very system dependent. For testing purposes, a PRNG would probably suffice.

Comment: @Michael: yes, now it's working. Seemed to be a server error. I'm gonna delete my comments.

Answer (score 0):

What I propose is the implementation of a well-known algorithm for the extraction of 32 Bit random numbers (KISS () function); the seed, for randomization, is _RndXSeed0 which can be set with the system timer with _RndXSeed0 = Round (Frac (Time) * 4294967295).

```
.386p
IDEAL
MODEL FLAT
CODESEG

PUBLIC _RndXSeed0 DD 123456789 ; X: Seed
PUBLIC _RndXSeed1 DD 362436000 ; Y: Must be <>0
PUBLIC _RndXSeed2 DD 521288629 ; Z: Must be <>0
PUBLIC _RndXSeed3 DD 7654321   ; C: Must be <>0

PUBLIC rndx_
rndx_:

; Returns a 32 Bit random number

     Push  ESI

     LEA   ESI,_RndXSeed0

     Mov   EAX,[ESI]
     Mov   EDX,69069
     Mul   EDX
     Add   EAX,12345
     Mov   [ESI],EAX    ; RndXSeed[0]=69069*RndXSeed[0]+12345;

     Mov   EAX,[ESI+4]
     ShL   EAX,13
     XOr   [ESI+4],EAX  ; RndXSeed[1]=RndXSeed[1] XOr (RndXSeed[1] ShL 13);

     Mov   EAX,[ESI+4]
     ShR   EAX,17
     XOr   [ESI+4],EAX  ; RndXSeed[1]=RndXSeed[1] XOr (RndXSeed[1] ShR 17);

     Mov   EAX,[ESI+4]
     ShL   EAX,5
     XOr   [ESI+4],EAX  ; RndXSeed[1]=RndXSeed[1] XOr (RndXSeed[1] ShL 5);

     Mov   EAX,[ESI+8]
     Mov   EDX,698769069
     Mul   EDX
     Add   EAX,[ESI+12]
     AdC   EDX,0        ; EDX:EAX=698769069*RndXSeed[2]+RndXSeed[3];

     Mov   [ESI+12],EDX ; RndXSeed[3]=T ShR 32;

     Cmp   EAX,[ESI+8]
     Mov   EAX,0
     SetE  AL

     Or    EDX,EDX
     SetE  DL

     And   AL,DL       ; EAX=CARDINAL(RndXSeed[2]=T)

     Add   EAX,[ESI]
     Add   EAX,[ESI+4] ; RndX=RndXSeed[0]+RndXSeed[1]+CARDINAL(RndXSeed[2]=T);

     Pop   ESI

     Ret

;-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

END
.
```